# Show/ hide Unity 3D elements

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I hope I am posting in the correct section. I know that it is possible to write a custom code in Unity so I have the following questions:

1. Imagine a house model in Unity. Would it be possible to have a code which helps to hide/unhide certain objects? For example, letter "W" would hide/unhide all windows, letter "C"  would hide/unhide all columns etc.
2. If it would be possible to develop a code for that, what would be the workflow? How would Unity know what is window and what is door?
3. Taking one step further.. Would it be possible to have a code that unhides the next step of the project. For example, the first step would be building foundations. Would it be possible to have a code that would unhide the next step, say, 1st floor floor element, with a klick of a keyboard key? And then with the same key unhide the next step which might be 1st floor walls. And would it be possible with another key go backwards?
4. If such code would be possible, what do you think would be the workflow? How would Unity know which element is in which step?

Answer (score 0):

Yes just have a class with an array of objects to show/hide and another property for what button will do it. Then just have a method that will hide/unhide each object in that class. In the update method of a behavior just check the input and call the method of the class based on what button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

---

## Would it be possible to have a code which helps to hide/unhide?

Yes, you can do that by calling GameObject.SetActive() function

```
door.SetActive(true); // door is a game object;
```

---

## How would Unity know what is window and what is door?

You can give the window/door a name, then access the game object by name

```
var door = GameObject.Find("MyDoor") as GameObject;
```

---

## Would it be possible to have a code that would show the next step, say, 1st floor floor element, with a klick of a keyboard key?

Yes, you can do that with code snippet below:

```
int step = 1;
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){
        print("space key was pressed");
        step++;
    }

    if(step == 1) {
    // do sth
    }
    else if(step == 2) {
    // do sth
    }               
}
```

---

Given the above snippet, your last answer can be easily deduced.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways of doing what you asked.

**1st way**

```
GameObject[] walls;
walls = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Wall");

foreach (GameObject wall in walls) 
{
    wall.setActive(true);
}
```

What you will have to do, besides the code, is to assign to those object a correct tag (like "Wall" "Window" "WatheverYouWillNeed"). So you can easily find all objects by giving them some kind of order (with tags).

***Best practice tip***

You may want to create a static class "Tags", and set public constants string inside the class, with all tag names.

```
public static class Tags
{
    public static const WINDOW_TAG = "Window";
    // ... more tags
}
```

**2nd way**

If what you want to set is only "visibility", you may want to modify only camera tag rendering. It doesn't even require any cycle at all. When you want to view windows, you just tell your camera to render the tag "Window".

```
// Turns on Windows Layer on mask using an OR operation
private void Show() 
{
    camera.cullingMask |= 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Window");
}

// Turn off the bit using an AND operation with the complement of the shifted int:
private void Hide() 
{
    camera.cullingMask &= ~(1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Window"));
}
```

It may look odd the second option, but keep in mind that the cullingMask is composed of bits, and every bit is a Layer defined by your tags. The "Everything" culling mask is 111111. If you want to see only Window, for example, and window is the last element, your culling mask would look something like 0000001

Hope it helped! :)