# Hide all tagged GameObjects upon button click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to combine these two:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1171111/hideunhide-game-object.html

[Show/ hide Unity 3D elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266383/show-hide-unity-3d-elements?rq=1)

I got this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Modify_Menu_Button_Handler : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject[] buttons_in_create_menu;
        buttons_in_create_menu = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("CreateMenu");
    }

    public void ChangeMenu()
    {
        foreach (GameObject button in buttons_in_create_menu)
        {
            button.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

But, the foreach line is red-underlined, saying the buttons_in_create_menu doesn't exist in the current context.

Coming from Javascript, I'm not sure how scope works in C# and especially within Unity's game loop. Thought the Start() function would be called upon the scene loading, based on the Unity docs: [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: Case sensitive. Always remember that this. And a variable declared in start. Is only in start

Comment: I don't see any case errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the variable globally in the class.

Like this:

```
public class Modify_Menu_Button_Handler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] buttons_in_create_menu;
    void Start()
    {
        buttons_in_create_menu = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("CreateMenu");
    }

    public void ChangeMenu()
    {
        foreach (GameObject button in buttons_in_create_menu)
        {
            button.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```